# Python2.7 and PyQt4 QFileDialog permission denied IOError

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I used the PyQt QFileDialog widget to get the user input file name. I then tried to use a Python csv writer to create my file. However, sometimes (not always, and i'm not sure why) I get an IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/mypathname/'

```
#this is how I set my file path parameter
self.dlg.ui.filepath.setText(QFileDialog.getSaveFileName())
self.pathString = str(self.dlg.ui.filePath.text())

#how i write the file
with open(self.pathString, 'wb') as ofile:
    writer = csv.writer(ofile, quoting=csv.QUOTE-NON, delimiter='\t'
    ...
```

Comment: Do you have write permissions for the target file?

Comment: @RickardSjogren If you're asking whether or not I have write permissions for the disk (in terms of server administration parameters), yes. If that's not what you're asking, how I can verify?